# Can I use select2 purely as a tokenizer, disabling the dropdown/search/match functionality?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-select2

I have multiple instances of select2 elements in my form, but in one of them (which is on a hidden input) I want to just tokenize the input.

I dont want the dropdown to ever show because it always shows "no matches found" and it confuses users. So I need to disable just the dropdown and use select2 as only a tokenizer for that specific element. Is that possible?

(I know I can do this easily with out the plugin but I want to use the plugin as it decorates the tokens and removes icon and it will be uniform with other inputs that use it)

Comment: It's little confusing what you're trying to do.  Could you post a screenshot or something that shows what you want?

Comment: I am trying to use select2 just to tokenize the input as the user types in. I just want the plugin to convert the entered text into tags (splitting commas and spaces),without opening the dropdown selection list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Used the approach described by @Paralife.

Found there is a option `dropdownCss` which sets the dropdown style. So `dropdownCss:{display:'none'}` is enough to disable it as well.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution: 
In the constructor, I put the option `dropdownCssClass: 'noshow'` and then just css it:
`.noshow { display:none !important;}`

This always hides the whole dropdown.